# How to set X-Robots-Tag HTTP header to "index; follow" in IIS or web.config?

Tags: iis, web-crawler, seo, pagerank

I get 'X-Robots-Tag: noindex; nofollow' in my response header. I want that to be set to 'index; follow'.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use url rewrite to modify the response header in iis, the URL Rewrite module can be downloaded here: [Download URL Rewrite Module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

More information about how to modify HTTP response header you can refer to below links:

[Modifying HTTP Response Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/modifying-http-response-headers)

https://port135.com/change-remove-response-headers

Comment: @samvu It is not the answer I was looking for, my doubt is completely on 'X-Robots-Tag" HTTP Header.

Comment: What does `my doubt is completely on "X-Robots-Tag" HTTP Header` mean?

Comment: My doubt has nothing to do with URL Rewrites. I just want to add 'X-Robots-Tag: index; follow' to my HTTP response Header.

Comment: Do you want to modify the value of "X-Robots-Tag" or add the value of X-Robots-Tag? In the content you posted, you want to change "noindex; nofollow" to "index; follow". If this is the case, then in iis you can only use iis url rewrite to change.

Comment: It is not working for me, can you please suggest any other method?

Comment: Sorry, as far as I know, the only thing that can modify the http response header in IIS is url rewrite